# Random img saving error on some iPhone 4s and iPod Touches

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimage

i encountered a weird error. i will like the app to save an image into camera roll.

but a small amount of device are giving me error saving msg.

EDIT: ERROR Log

"Failed to encode image for saved photos." UserInfo=0x3e7170 {NSUnderlyingError=0x389310 "Failed to encode image for saved photos.", NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to encode image for saved photos.

```
May 22 14:13:34 unknown assetsd[281] <Error>: ImageIO: CGImageDestinationAddImage image parameter is nil
May 22 14:13:34 unknown assetsd[281] <Error>: ImageIO: CGImageDestinationFinalize image destination does not have enough images
May 22 14:13:34 unknown assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextSetBaseCTM: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextSetInterpolationQuality: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown com.apple.assetsd[281] <Notice>: May 22 14:13:34 SLQ-iTouch assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown com.apple.assetsd[281] <Notice>: May 22 14:13:34 SLQ-iTouch assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown com.apple.assetsd[281] <Notice>: May 22 14:13:34 SLQ-iTouch assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextSetBaseCTM: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown com.apple.assetsd[281] <Notice>: May 22 14:13:34 SLQ-iTouch assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown com.apple.assetsd[281] <Notice>: May 22 14:13:34 SLQ-iTouch assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextSetInterpolationQuality: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown com.apple.assetsd[281] <Notice>: May 22 14:13:34 SLQ-iTouch assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown com.apple.assetsd[281] <Notice>: May 22 14:13:34 SLQ-iTouch assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown com.apple.assetsd[281] <Notice>: May 22 14:13:34 SLQ-iTouch assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown com.apple.assetsd[281] <Notice>: May 22 14:13:34 SLQ-iTouch assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown com.apple.assetsd[281] <Notice>: May 22 14:13:34 SLQ-iTouch assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown com.apple.assetsd[281] <Notice>: May 22 14:13:34 SLQ-iTouch assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown com.apple.assetsd[281] <Notice>: May 22 14:13:34 SLQ-iTouch assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown com.apple.assetsd[281] <Notice>: May 22 14:13:34 SLQ-iTouch assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown com.apple.assetsd[281] <Notice>: May 22 14:13:34 SLQ-iTouch assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown com.apple.assetsd[281] <Notice>: May 22 14:13:34 SLQ-iTouch assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown com.apple.assetsd[281] <Notice>: May 22 14:13:34 SLQ-iTouch assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown com.apple.assetsd[281] <Notice>: May 22 14:13:34 SLQ-iTouch assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown assetsd[281] <Error>: CGBitmapContextCreateImage: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown com.apple.assetsd[281] <Notice>: May 22 14:13:34 SLQ-iTouch assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown com.apple.assetsd[281] <Notice>: May 22 14:13:34 SLQ-iTouch assetsd[281] <Error>: CGBitmapContextCreateImage: invalid context 0x0
>
```

below are my code used to save the images.

```
- (IBAction)saveImage:(id)sender {

    HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    HUD.dimBackground = YES;
    HUD.labelText = @"Its saving!";
    self.imageOverlay.alpha = 1;
    self.savedImage = [self maskImage:self.imgView withMask:self.baseImgView];

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.savedImage, self, @selector(imageSavedToPhotosAlbum: didFinishSavingWithError: contextInfo:), nil);
}

- (void)imageSavedToPhotosAlbum:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo {

    NSString *message;
    NSString *title;

    if (!error) {
        title = NSLocalizedString(@"Save Success", @"");
        message = NSLocalizedString(@"Save Success Message", @"");
        HUD.customView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Checkmark.png"]];
        HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView; 
        HUD.labelText = @"We’re saved - WooHoo!!";
        [HUD hide:YES afterDelay:1.5];
        saved =1;
        self.imageOverlay.alpha =0.85;
        [self performSelector:@selector(saveSuccess) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.5];


    } else 
    {
        title = NSLocalizedString(@"Save Failed", @"");
        message = [error description];

        HUD.customView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sad_face.png"]];
        HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;
        HUD.labelText = @"Error! Try saving photo again :p";
        [HUD hide:YES afterDelay:3];
    }
}

- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImageView *)maskImage withMask:(UIImageView *)cropImage
{

    UIImage *image = nil;
    UIImage *imagePNG = nil;

    CGSize newImageSize = CGSizeMake(cropImage.frame.size.width, cropImage.frame.size.height);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newImageSize, NO, 0.0); //retina res
    [self.viewForImg.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    

    NSData *imgData =  UIImagePNGRepresentation ( image ); // get PNG representation
    imagePNG = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData]; // wrap UIImage around PNG representation
    return imagePNG;
}
```

Comment: What the you get when saving?

Comment: Could you add the error message to your question?

Comment: HI thanks for the reply.
i managed to create the log, as is is random

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImageView *)maskImage withMask:(UIImageView *)cropImage
{

    UIImage *image = nil;
    UIImage *imagePNG = nil;

    CGSize newImageSize = CGSizeMake(cropImage.frame.size.width, cropImage.frame.size.height);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newImageSize, NO, 0.0); //retina res
    [self.viewForImg.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    NSData *imgData =  UIImagePNGRepresentation ( image ); // get PNG representation
    imagePNG = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData]; // wrap UIImage around PNG representation
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    

    return imagePNG;
}
```